# How do I know what dungeon I'm in?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

A few of the old-world dungeons in World of Warcraft that were truly epic places with more content then some of the later raids have been split up in the dungeon finder so it can be done a couple ways.  Depending on the particular "mode", it changes who the final boss is, and knowing who it is is important for getting your bag of crap and other bonuses.

My problem is specifically with BRD, one way it ends at the warden ("Detention Block"), the other at the king ("Upper City").  Both start you at the beginning of the instance (unlike Maraudon where it will fling you half-way through it if you just need Princess)

Comment: So do you want to find out *what* dungeon you're in or *where* in the dungeon you are?

Comment: @Anna, what dungeon, e.g. "Blackrock Depths - Detention Block" vs. "Blackrock Depths - Upper City"

Comment: That's the same dungeon, just different entrance points. There's no way to distinguish them beyond just knowing what each part looks like and how to get to one from the other.

Comment: @Anna They actually have the same entrance point. It's just that the 'random dungeon bonus' only fires for a different set of bosses. Which is pretty infuriating.

Comment: @LessPop Oh, seriously? That's lame. I've never run the random queue on BRD. Come to think of it, I haven't run BRD since pre-Cata, which really invalidates all I've said. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hilariously, there is no way to determine what dungeon objectives you've been assigned until you complete them.

There is some anecdotal evidence that it's more often than not the *lesser* of the dungeon objectives (for example, LBRS instead of UBRS), but most likely a form of selection bias is at work there.

Answer (score 0):

Blackrock Depths and Blackrock Spire are the only dungeons I know of that have this problem, luckily. The only thing you can do is ask your group and hope that at least someone queued for a specific version of the dungeon **and** actually remembers what the "Dungeon group ready" dialog said.

Comment: Blackrock Spire also has this issue.

Comment: Whoops, forgot. Fixed!